# Battery level check background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, battery

I need to check the device's battery level when my app is in the background (just swiped, not closed). iOS 13 provides background tasks, but all my code don't work.

My code worked only one time, when in

```
didEnterBackground
```

and that all

For example, I need to check the battery level (90-80 and etc) every 1 minute when my app is in background. How can I do it?

Comment: Why would you need to check the battery while your app is in the background?

Comment: And why would you check your battery every minute? Just monitor if the battery level changed.

Comment: Btw AFAIK as long as your app is active it will continue to receive the battery notifications if you are monitoring it.

Comment: @LeoDabus it's for example ,

Comment: @LeoDabus not every minute , maybe like a 5 min , Notification don't work when app in background

Comment: As I said if the app still active it does. You can't run a timer while the app is in background

Comment: yep , question about background :)